# cloud run removed Continuously deploy from a bitbucket repository?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I used to deploy my projects to Cloud Run with continuously deploy from a bitbucket repository.
But I found that Cloud Run removed this option a few days ago?
How should I continuously deploy my projects from a bitbucket repository now?
[image][image]

now i can only build the project manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.BitBucket repository being no longer available for Cloud Run continuous deployment. Now, only GitHub remains as a Repository Provider. The Bitbucket section was removed from the [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build#setup-cd) also.

FYI, Cloud Run's "continuous deployment" setup has always been a UI shortcut on top of Cloud Build Triggers.

> How should I continuously deploy my projects from a bitbucket repository now?

You  can use a [Cloud Build Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/triggers). Refer to [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run) and [blog](https://notch.health/blogs/tech-solutions/from-code-to-deployment-with-bitbucket-cloud-build-and-cloud-run) on how to deploy to cloud run.

Incase if you still want to continue with bitbucket from cloud run, you may consider raising a [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) by describing your request in detail.